# Python 3.6 - Deployment to Heroku - Using Pipenv lock to add requirements falis because of a mismatch in subdependencies for the celery library

Tags: python, django, heroku, locking, celery

I am trying to configure my Django app for deployment to Heroku. When I attempt to lock my Pipfiles using `pipenv lock --verbose` I get the following error, saying that I have a mismatch in my sub-dependencies, and celery 4.1.0 could not be found. Here is the error:

```
Finding the best candidates:
  found candidate amqp==2.2.2 (constraint was >=2.1.4,==2.2.2,<3.0)
  found candidate anyjson==0.3.3 (constraint was ==0.3.3)
  found candidate arrow==0.12.0 (constraint was ==0.12.0)
  found candidate beautifulsoup4==4.6.0 (constraint was ==4.6.0)
  found candidate billiard==3.5.0.3 (constraint was >=3.5.0.2,==3.5.0.3,<3.6.0)
  found candidate blessed==1.14.2 (constraint was ==1.14.2)
  found candidate bs4==0.0.1 (constraint was ==0.0.1)
Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
Could not find a version that matches celery<4.0,<5.0,==4.1.0,>=3.1.15,>=4.0
```

When I run `pipenv graph` I see that Django-celery, and Django-celery-beat both use celery as dependencies

```
django-celery==3.2.2
  - celery [required: >=3.1.15,<4.0, installed: 3.1.25]
django-celery-beat==1.1.0
  - celery [required: <5.0,>=4.0, installed: 3.1.25]
```

The dependencies of these libraries call an older version of celery, when I have Celery 4.1.0. I assume that when I attempt to lock my requirements, that these must be the same? I've tried looking online and was unable to find a way a solution to this mismatch in dependencies. I've tried specifying *  for the celery version, and I've tried installing Django-celery and Django-celery-beat with install of celery 4.1.0 like:

```
pip3 install Django-celery celery>=4.1.0
```

When I do this, it just says that it's already installed. How else can I try fixing this issue? My Pipfile file looks like

> Pipfile

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[requires]

python_version = "3.6"


[packages]

amqp = "==2.2.2"
anyjson = "==0.3.3"
arrow = "==0.12.0"
beautifulsoup4 = "==4.6.0"
billiard = "==3.5.0.3"
blessed = "==1.14.2"
bs4 = "==0.0.1"
celery = "==4.1.0"
certifi = "==2017.7.27.1"
chardet = "==3.0.4"
click = "==6.7"
dj-database-url = "==0.4.2"
Django = "==2.0"
django-celery = "==3.2.2"
django-celery-beat = "==1.1.0"
django-celery-results = "==1.0.1"
django-heroku = "==0.2.0"
django-picklefield = "==1.0.0"
django-q = "==0.8.1"
django-redis-cache = "==1.7.1"
enum-compat = "==0.0.2"
eventlet = "==0.21.0"
flake8 = "==3.5.0"
greenlet = "==0.4.12"
gunicorn = "==19.7.1"
idna = "==2.6"
itsdangerous = "==0.24"
Jinja2 = "==2.10"
kombu = "==4.1.0"
MarkupSafe = "==1.0"
mccabe = "==0.6.1"
numpy = "==1.13.3"
olefile = "==0.44"
pandas = "==0.21.0"
pew = "==1.1.1"
Pillow = "==4.3.0"
pipenv = "==9.0.0"
psutil= "==5.3.1"
psycopg2 = "==2.7.3.2"
pycodestyle = "==2.3.1"
pycurl = "==7.43.0.1"
pyflakes = "==1.6.0"
python-dateutil = "==2.6.1"
pytz = "==2017.3"
redis = "==2.10.6"
requests = "==2.18.4"
selenium = "==3.7.0"
six = "==1.11.0"
urllib3 = "==1.22"
vine = "==1.1.4"
virtualenv = "==15.1.0"
virtualenv-clone = "==0.2.6"
wcwidth= "==0.1.7"
Werkzeug = "==0.12.2"
whitenoise = "==3.3.1"


[dev-packages]
```

Hope you can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-celery` is no longer required to be installed to use celery with django. Uninstall it. That will clear up your dependency issue.

From the [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

> Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work with Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case.